# Retrieve records count from has_many relation

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following models

```
Bookrack.rb
has_many :faculties

Faculty.rb
belongs_to :bookrack
has_many :books

Book.rb
belongs_to :faculty
has_many :barcodes

Barcode.rb
belongs_to :book
```

I have a controller name bookrack controller. I can extract record of barcode in Bookrack using loop and empty array. Is there any simpler method to extract barcode record from Bookrack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably help..

Bookrack.rb

```
has_many :faculties
has_many :books, through: :faculties
has_many :barcodes, through: :books
```

Then you can do,

```
Bookrack.find(1).barcodes.count
```

Also to note that, `has_many` relations has to be plural, your model seems inappropriate..or correct it if it's a typo..

Comment: Thanks a lot. You save my hours

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this (for example for counting barcodes of the first book in the first faculty in the first bookrack):

```
b = Bookrack.first.faculties.first.books.first.barcodes.count
```

Answer (score 1):

With model relationships like:

```
# app/models/bookrack.rb
has_many :faculties

# app/models/faculty.rb
belongs_to :bookrack
has_many :books

# app/models/book.rb
belongs_to :faculty
has_many :barcodes

# app/models/barcode.rb
belongs_to :book
```

You could use [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins) in a "nested" way:

```
Bookrack.joins(faculties: [books: :barcodes]).count
# => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "bookracks" 
#    INNER JOIN "faculties" ON "faculties"."bookrack_id" = "bookracks"."id" 
#    INNER JOIN "books" ON "books"."faculty_id" = "faculties"."id" 
#    INNER JOIN "barcodes" ON "barcodes"."book_id" = "books"."id"
# => 1
```